# CGPath draw a loader

Tags: iphone, loader, cabasicanimation, cgpath, caanimation

I juste watch this effect :

[alt text http://grab.by/5UBM](http://grab.by/5UBM)

I would like to reproduce it. Is it simply a CGPath animation? Have you got some indications so implement this beautiful loader view ? Thanks for your tips ;)

Comment: The image link is broken so we can't see the effect. Kind of hard to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that hard actually.

I don't have time to write the code (although it would be relativly easy), but I'll give you a hint: use a timer and arc.

Comment: Yeah I don't want a code just hint I wanna success by myself ;) so AddLineToArc ? But I don't know how to color a CGPath

Comment: Sorry, I was away for a while.
Yes, add arc method would do (just look in the documentation).

You don't set a color to the particular path, youjust set the color.
Here's an example [[UIColor redColor] set]. You can also choose to set only the fill color (setFill) or the stroke color (setStroke).

Comment: Yes ok but I have to implement some CGContext ?

Comment: You have to make a CGPath and add the arc to it. Then add the path to CGContext, and draw the path with CGContext.

Comment: Ok! Thanks !
So I made that and it works (http://grab.by/61nH) :

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {

 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 
 CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
 CGPathAddArc(path, NULL, 150, 200, 100, 270*(PI/180), 280*(PI/180), false);
 CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1, 0, 0, 1);
 CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 20);
 CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 0), 30, [UIColor redColor].CGColor);
 CGContextAddPath(context, path);
 CGContextStrokePath(context); 
}
I added a timer and try something but doesn't work for increasing end angle

Comment: You mean you can't increase the angle of the arc?

Post your code, maybe I can help.

Comment: I posted my cade as a new answer